# Limit connection rights on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, security

I have an app to deploy in production that uses 'honor system' security. That is, all users connect to the DB using a SQL user/passwd credential and the app manages permissions itself. The latter part doesn't bother me as much as the fact that the connection object contains embedded credentials and can be copied around freely. I'm try to find some way to limit connections to a more limited set of clients. I can create firewall rules to limit by IP, of course. Is there any way to 'prequalify' SQL logins either by Machine account or domain membership?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: 2012, but I have downgrade rights if necessary. This app is definitely getting it's own instance.

Comment: Then the login triggers mentioned in the answers will be the way to go.  Just tie the username to the application name.  IF they don't match rollback. Now this won't be perfect because there are ways to fake the application name, but it'll be good enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this through a [Logon Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx).  In your logon trigger you can have the logic to do the necessary checks that you're looking for (such as machine name).  Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a way to grab the domain membership of the user if you are utilizing SQL Server Authentication.

You can look at using the [EVENTDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213611.aspx) function to see if you can extract other information to determine whether or not the connection should be allowed.  If you don't want that particular logon to be successful, you can simple conditionally test and issue a `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: I'll have to install a mixed-mode instance to verify, but it doesn't appear that any additional information is available to the logon trigger. Good to know, however. I was not aware of that feature.

Answer (score 12):

As Thomas mentioned that it can be done using LOGON Trigger. Below is the script that will help you out

```
/*

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Security/69558/
Credit: Gregory A. Ferdinandsen
--greg@ferdinandsen.com
--Revision 1.0, 8 Feb 10
--Requires SQL 2005 SP2 or higher
*/
if not exists (select 1 from master..sysdatabases where name = 'SQL_Audit')
 begin
 create database SQL_Audit
  end
USE [SQL_Audit]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BlackList](
[SRV_Rule] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[HostName] [varchar](64) NULL,
[IP_Address] [varchar](15) NULL,
[LoginName] [varchar](128) NULL,
[AppName] [varchar](256) NULL,
[RestrictionEnabled] [bit] NULL,
[Description] [varchar](2048) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_BlackList] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[SRV_Rule] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BlackList] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_BlackList_RestrictionEnabled] DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RestrictionEnabled]
GO

---------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------
USE [SQL_Audit]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Violations](
[ViolationNum] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[PostDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[LoginName] [varchar](128) NULL,
[IPAddress] [varchar](15) NULL,
[HostName] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
[ServerName] [varchar](96) NULL,
[AppName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
[ViolationType] [varchar](512) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Violations] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ViolationNum] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Violations] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Violations_PostDate] DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [PostDate]
GO
---------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------
--(c) Gregory A. Ferdinandsen
--greg@ferdinandsen.com
--Revision 1.0, 8 Feb 10
--Requires SQL 2005 SP2 or higher

--
--Change with <<Execute as 'Domain\SQL'>> for a valid service account that has sa rights
--
--Information on Logon Triggers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx
--
USE Master
go

CREATE Trigger [trg_LoginBlackList]
 on all Server 

 as
begin

 declare @data XML
declare @User as varchar(128)
declare @HostName as varchar(64)
declare @IPAddress as varchar(15)
declare @AppName as nvarchar(256)
declare @SPID as int
declare @SrvName as nvarchar(96)
declare @PostTime as datetime
declare @LogMsg as varchar(1024)

set @data = EVENTDATA()
set @User = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')
set @IPAddress = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ClientHost)[1]', 'nvarchar(15)')
set @SPID = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SPID)[1]', 'int')
set @SrvName = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ServerName)[1]', 'nvarchar(96)')
set @PostTime = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/PostTime)[1]', 'datetime')
set @HostName = Cast(Host_Name() as nvarchar(64))
set @AppName = Cast(App_Name() as nvarchar(256))

--Check to see if the blacklist table exists, if the table does not exist, exit the Trigger, as otherwise all user would be locked out.

if Not Exists (select * from SQL_Audit.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'BlackList')
begin
return;
end


--#1
--If a user connects from a given work station and with a given UserName, they will be dissconected
--This user need to be set up in SQL_Audit..Blacklist with a user name and a host name, no IP Address is necesary
--This is the prefered method of blacklisting, as DHCP could reak havoc on any IP restrictions
If(Exists(Select * from SQL_Audit.dbo.BlackList where LoginName = @User and HostName = @HostName and RestrictionEnabled = 1))
begin
--Any data modifications made up to the point of ROLLBACK TRANSACTION are rolled back
--The current trigger continues to execute any remaining statements that appear after the ROLLBACK statement. 
--If any of these statements modify data, the modifications are not rolled back.
--http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb153915.aspx
rollback

insert into SQL_Audit..Violations
(PostDate, LoginName, IPAddress, HostName, ServerName, AppName, ViolationType)
values (@PostTime, @User, @IPAddress, @HostName, @SrvName, @AppName, 'LoginName, HostName')

--Exit trigger without evaluating any further conditions
return;
end

--#2
--If a user connects from a given IP Address and with a given UserName, they will be dissconected
--This user need to be set up in SQL_Audit..Blacklist with a user name and a IP Address, no HostName is necesary
If(Exists(Select * from SQL_Audit.dbo.BlackList where LoginName = @User and IP_Address = @IPAddress and RestrictionEnabled = 1))
begin
--Any data modifications made up to the point of ROLLBACK TRANSACTION are rolled back
--The current trigger continues to execute any remaining statements that appear after the ROLLBACK statement. 
--If any of these statements modify data, the modifications are not rolled back.
--http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb153915.aspx
rollback

insert into SQL_Audit..Violations
(PostDate, LoginName, IPAddress, HostName, ServerName, AppName, ViolationType)
values (@PostTime, @User, @IPAddress, @HostName, @SrvName, @AppName, 'LoginName, IP Address')

--Exit trigger without evaluating any further conditions
return;
end

--#3
--If a user connects from a given Blacklisted IP Address, regardless of the host name or SQL Server User
--This IPAddress need to be set up in SQL_Audit..Blacklist with only an IP Address, no other information is needed
--This will block all connections from the designated IP Address
If(Exists(Select * from SQL_Audit.dbo.BlackList where IP_Address = @IPAddress and LoginName is NULL and HostName is NULL and RestrictionEnabled = 1))
begin
--Any data modifications made up to the point of ROLLBACK TRANSACTION are rolled back
--The current trigger continues to execute any remaining statements that appear after the ROLLBACK statement. 
--If any of these statements modify data, the modifications are not rolled back.
--http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb153915.aspx
rollback

insert into SQL_Audit..Violations
(PostDate, LoginName, IPAddress, HostName, ServerName, AppName, ViolationType)
values (@PostTime, @User, @IPAddress, @HostName, @SrvName, @AppName, 'IP Address')

--Exit trigger without evaluating any further conditions
return;
end

--#4
--If a user connects from a given Blacklisted Workstation, regardless of the IP Address or SQL Server User
--This Client need to be set up in SQL_Audit..Blacklist with only a value for HostName, no other information is needed
--This will block all connections from the designated Host
If(Exists(Select * from SQL_Audit.dbo.BlackList where HostName = @HostName and LoginName is NULL and IP_Address is NULL and RestrictionEnabled = 1))
begin
--Any data modifications made up to the point of ROLLBACK TRANSACTION are rolled back
--The current trigger continues to execute any remaining statements that appear after the ROLLBACK statement. 
--If any of these statements modify data, the modifications are not rolled back.
--http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb153915.aspx
rollback

insert into SQL_Audit..Violations
(PostDate, LoginName, IPAddress, HostName, ServerName, AppName, ViolationType)
values (@PostTime, @User, @IPAddress, @HostName, @SrvName, @AppName, 'HostName')

--Exit trigger without evaluating any further conditions
return;
end

--#5
--If a particular application connects to SQL Server, regardless of IP Address, UserName, or HostName, the session is terminated
If(Exists(Select * from SQL_Audit.dbo.BlackList where AppName = @AppName and HostName is NULL and LoginName is NULL and IP_Address is NULL and RestrictionEnabled = 1))
begin
--Any data modifications made up to the point of ROLLBACK TRANSACTION are rolled back
--The current trigger continues to execute any remaining statements that appear after the ROLLBACK statement. 
--If any of these statements modify data, the modifications are not rolled back.
--http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb153915.aspx
rollback

insert into SQL_Audit..Violations
(PostDate, LoginName, IPAddress, HostName, ServerName, AppName, ViolationType)
values (@PostTime, @User, @IPAddress, @HostName, @SrvName, @AppName, 'ApplicationName')

--Exit trigger without evaluating any further conditions
return;
end

--#6
--If a particular application connects to SQL Server, with a given UserName (i.e. service account cannot connect with SSMS)
If(Exists(Select * from SQL_Audit.dbo.BlackList where AppName = @AppName and LoginName = @User and RestrictionEnabled = 1))
begin
--Any data modifications made up to the point of ROLLBACK TRANSACTION are rolled back
--The current trigger continues to execute any remaining statements that appear after the ROLLBACK statement. 
--If any of these statements modify data, the modifications are not rolled back.
--http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb153915.aspx
rollback

insert into SQL_Audit..Violations
(PostDate, LoginName, IPAddress, HostName, ServerName, AppName, ViolationType)
values (@PostTime, @User, @IPAddress, @HostName, @SrvName, @AppName, 'ApplicationName, UserName')

--Exit trigger without evaluating any further conditions
return;
end
end;

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ENABLE TRIGGER [trg_LoginBlackList] ON ALL SERVER
GO
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `Host_Name()` is *not* secure and can be easily spoofed by just about anyone.  It's particularly easy to do from Excel.  Your `@IPAddress` would be a lot more reliable for this purpose.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Good point and thats why it has IP address as well. Also, it wont work for the existing connections and it a limitation of Logon triggers. All new connections will go through the Logon Trigger. Thanks for your comment.