# Avoid user login Directly to AlwaysOn High Availability Primary

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, high-availability

I have setup an AlwaysOn High Availability in Sql Server 2014.
my IP addresses are according to this :

```
192.168.1.189  -- Listener
192.168.1.180  -- Replica
192.168.1.181  -- Primary
```

Right now users can login to my Primary directly and I want to avoid this.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few questions that are similar to what you are asking, may be board-line duplicate but either way:

- [Protect SQL Server from hackers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/52414/507)
- [Limit connection rights to SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/37379/507)

That second question listed is probably the duplicate of this one.

Overall if you are looking at ensuring logins can only access via the listener you are going to have problems trying to use a login trigger. I am not sure you can pick up DNS or IP address it used to actually connect to SQL Server. If it can then it would be a viable option.

I would opt to use your firewall or network infrastructure. A firewall can be much more efficient and easier to manage with blocking access to either the IP or access from an IP range to a specific IP.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could disable the login on the primary side and enable it on the read-only secondary.  This would force users to use the Listener, connecting with `applicationintent=readonly`

You'll have to make sure your replica's can be used as Read-Only and be sure to setup the routing accordingly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-read-only-routing-for-an-availability-group-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

You could use an agent job to frequently check the replica's status (primary/secondary) and modify the login accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Actually I don't have access to firewall and DNS.
I have to handle it by SQL Server.
Also It should handled automatically, because of the I cant handle it manually.

Comment: You don't need access to the firewall or DNS.  Configuration is done via SSMS and/or queries to configure the system.  I set up an entire without access to either.